# Given two arbitrary terms of a geometric series, can this lead to geometric series parameters that cannot be solved for in terms of radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

So some higher degree polynomials (and polynomial systems) can still have their roots be solved for in terms of radicals. It comes down to Galois groups and I'm a bit rusty on that subject so I don't know the answer to this question. Given two arbitrary terms $x_m$ and $x_n$ coming from a geometric series, i.e. $x_j = a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots + ar^{j-1}$ , is it always possible to solve for the parameters $a,r$ of the geometric series in terms of $x_m$ and $x_n$, using radicals?

Comment: This doesn’t seem to have anything to do with Galois theory. But have you solved this in any specific cases at all? Like, maybe, when $n=m+1\,$?